# Bizarre caching of "dead" DNS entries; where is this cache stored?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, dns, arp

This has really got me stumped.

[Advanced IP Scanner](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) has the ability to show "dead" entries—devices that were at some point visible on the network, but which are no longer reachable.
Specifically, I can see the devices' last-known host names, NetBIOS names, IP addresses, MAC addresses, and even *manufacturers*.

This wouldn't be so weird if it weren't for the fact that I still see these ***even if*** I disable my network card, clear my DNS cache, and reboot while still disconnected from any network. I don't see this information anywhere else... not in `ipconfig /displaydns`, not in `arp -a`, not anywhere else.

The fact that this information persists across reboots and network disconnections implies it *has* to be stored somewhere on my computer itself.
For the life of me, I cannot figure out **where** these entries are stored. I've searched the registry, the files in my \Windows folder, the application's files, etc. **but the entries are nowhere to be found**.
Furthermore, I've even tried using Process Monitor, API Monitor, etc. to monitor the API calls, but I still cannot figure out where this information is coming from.

#### Where on my system are these dead entries stored?

Please note that I am **NOT** asking how to hide the information or anything else. I'm *specifically* trying to figure out **where** they are stored on my system.

Comment: Try to restart your router, Advanced IP Scanner query routers DNS forwarder and gathering info from there

Comment: @Alex: Did you read paragraph 3? I said this occurs even when I'm disconnected and my network adapter is **turned off**... you're telling me to restart my router?

Comment: Disconnection from router didn't clear ROUTER's cache. Yes, power cycle your router

Comment: @Alex: The question was *"where is this cache stored"*, not *"how do I clear this cache"*. Clearing the router's cache is irrelevant when this information is on my computer and the two are utterly disconnected. How in the world do you think my router is providing my computer with this information when I'm specifically telling you my computer is **not connected** to the router?

Comment: When you disconnected from network, `Advanced IP scanner` maintaining its own cache, I think it keep it encrypted inside `service_probes` that lives in AppData\local\temp\Advanced Port scanner. If you delete completely the whole this temporary directory and will try scan again while disconnected then "dead" entries will disappear

Comment: @Alex: That's wrong (that's not what's happening here), but I figured out why we're talking past each other. I'm running version 2.3.2161, whereas you're probably talking about a later version, like 2.4.3021. My version doesn't do what you're saying. Furthermore, the newer version does *not* show these dead devices even though I've enabled showing dead devices—only the old version does. Try finding the older version (e.g. [here](http://advanced-ip-scanner.windows8compatible.com/)) to see what I mean.

Comment: @Alex: OH, actually, never mind, I have to correct my last comment: I found the problem. It's in a file named `advanced_ip_scanner_MAC.bin`. I'm guessing the reason I couldn't find it earlier was that it is storing the data in Unicode, not ASCII. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest one version 2.4.2679. It still showing `dead` entries if you would keep that temp folder. When I disconnecting some of devices from network, clearing the DNS cache, they are (`dead`) still in AdvIPScanner marked as grey-outed. Sometimes it is really annoying when walking between clients and if they have the same LAN IP ranges then AdvIPscanner showing dead entries from others clients were I was

Comment: Yes I forget exact file name, just remember it was in temp folder and when I need to clear up those `dead` entries, I just removing the whole temp folder (Easier to remember what to do in such cases :) )

Comment: I moved our conversation to the answer, so someone may find it useful in case he/she need to get rid of `dead` entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our investigation with OP finally narrowed to the particular file that is responsible for keeping mysterious `dead` entries.

The file that keep results of previous scans located in the file  `advanced_ip_scanner_MAC.bin` that in turn stored in `%AppData%\local\temp\Advanced Port Scanner 2`. (It keeps text as Unicode characters, so not trivial to find if one searching for ASCII strings.)

Advanced IP scanner uses this file to show disconnected devices that were found with previous scans as `dead` entries. It could be useful if one need to wake up over WOL some devices, but it could be annoying if you travel between job sites and see such `dead` entries from others network, so if you don't need to keep results of previous scans, simply delete or rename this `advanced_ip_scanner_MAC.bin` file

Comment: I will add anecdotally that yes--the above solution of deleting the file (actually 3 files exist, similar name but replace MAC with "alias" and "comments") works.  HOWEVER, I found that even after deleting and closing the scanner, I reopened and the dead entries persisted.  Rebooting finally removed them, so perhaps the program caches in memory or some other "temp" file in the Temp folder.   
Also my files were not in \local\Temp\***\, but were in the root of \users\username\

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember what version this appeared, but on the Settings|Options menu, select Misc.  There is a button at the bottom of the page to 'Clear scan history'.

Not exactly the most obvious location for that feature, but it is easier than finding the file and erasing that.

Comment: Needs converted to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using Advanced IP Scanner it is possible to clear all of the previous stored information. Navigate to

> Settings -> Options -> Misc -> Delete Stored Data.

Worked for me and showed just what was currently on my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosts file (I'm assuming windows here).

The location is C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.

Comment: I did and there is nothing in there. These are dynamically found devices my system originally knew nothing about.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Is it possible that this is application data being stored by Advanced IP Scanner?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late for an answer, but today I found these files (Windows 10) here:

```
%HOME PATH%

advanced_ip_scanner_Aliases.bin

advanced_ip_scanner_Comments.bin

advanced_ip_scanner_MAC.bin
```

and even with the latest version 2.5.3850, in Settings/Options/Miscellaneous,
the [Delete Stored Data] button does not do its job.

So, to have a fresh list, I simply delete these files.

Et voila ! (better late than never)

Answer (score 0):

Not for Advanced IP Scanner but usually you run these commands to reset DNS cache in Windows (order is important):

```
ipconfig /release *
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew *
ipconfig /registerdns
```